# Common primary key across a collection of DataTables

Tags: c#, database-design, ado.net, datatable, database-normalization

I have a class, let's call it `TableOwner`, and one of its fields is a `DataTable` with a column for name (which is also the primary key) and a column for amount. So there is one primary key column and a second non-primary column.

In my program, I create a collection of `TableOwner` instances. The collection is essentially a set: Logically there is no order of `TableOwner`'s, it only matters how many of each kind exist. Each one's `DataTable` is populated with different values for amount, but they all have the same primary key.

For example, imagine `TableOwner` is used to store data on bank accounts. Each instance represents one account, then the `DataTable` might record how much of each currency there is in the account. For every account, the number of dollars, euros or pounds in that account may differ, but *for every account, there is data on these same three currencies, even if the amount is 0 (no money in account) or `null` (perhaps data is missing)*. So basically I want a 2-D table or matrix, but my class hierarchy impedes me from implementing it as such.

What is a sensible way to deal with all of this? I can think of the following approaches:

1) Make a `DataColumn` first and then pass it to all new instances of `TableOwner` to be used for their own `DataTable`'s. Downside: If I later decide I want to remove a row from the primary key (eg the user decides "You know what, I don't care about euros anymore, dump all the data on them and remove the column."), I must iterate through the whole collection and remove the row from each `TableOwner`'s table one by one.

2) Make a single `DataTable` used by all of the `TableOwner` instances (perhaps make it a static field). Instead of one amount column, the table will have many columns, such as Amount1, Amount2 and so on. Every `TableOwner` instance creates its own amount column at initialization and remembers its name for later - now removing a row is an elementary DB operation. Downside: Seems inelegant and "wrong".

As you can see, both have a downside. Is there a better way?

Apologies if the question is very basic or worded strangely, as I don't know much about databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a table with Columns for Owner, Currency and Amount

So instead of

```
 Owner1 20$ £30 €40
```

You have three records

```
 Owner | Currency | Amount
 Owner1  $          20
 Owner1  £          30
 Owner1  €          40
```

(Where the currency symbols represent Currency IDs from a separate Currency table)

If a person doesn't have an amount in a particular currency, then there is no record for the combination of person and currency.

This is part of the process of [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: So if I am keeping track of n quantities for m objects, the table will have n*m rows and 3 columns?

Comment: Yes. And if you want to add a new type of object M, you can do that without changing your table structure.

Comment: Thanks (I was just about to ask what this process is called, too)!